# Stretch table row to background image's height

Tags: html, css

I want to strect the table row to the image's height...without assigning any height to the table row...when i assign height value to table row then it shows the image but i dont want to assign the height to table row..

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello Stack overflow</td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td style="background-image: url(http://localhost:/Data/SF8-P72/data/SF8-P72/files/71D559BD-C5F4-D9C2-837D-E297B9916944.png); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One way to force height on the `td` would be to add a padding in % to it. It won't produce the actual image height though, just a % height with respect to the container width. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/odn7y9ny/1/) - Is that something like what you were after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an image as background, its size is not evaluated for any layouting. That said you have to either set the dimensions explicitly or use an img tag, which dimensions are calculated as soon as the image is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```css
td
{
  border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>Hello Stack overflow</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://www.avaloncommunities.com/~/media/Images/Brand%20Photos/Home%20Photos/homepage_carousel_blue_small.png?h=250&la=en&w=350"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yaa but u have used img <img> tag...i want it using background img

Comment: Sorry it's not possible using just CSS. You need JQuery/JavaScript for that.